# Compute $\int_0^2 x^3 d[x]$ using Riemann–Stieltjes

Tags: real-analysis

I am to compute Compute $\int_0^2 x^3 d[x]$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. I can think of this somewhat graphically, where at $[0,1)$ a straight line lies at $y=0$, $[1,2)$ a straight line lies at $y=1$. But using the [Riemann Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), I am somewhat confused. Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^2 x^3\,d[x]=\sum_{n=1}^2n^3=9$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate why the integral becomes the sum? I don't see it right away. I tried to divide the integral to sub-intervals of the form $[n,n+1)$ and say that $[x]$ is the same as $x$ on these sub-intervals but I got a different answer. In fact, I got $4$. I would appreciate it if you told me what I had done wrong as well. Thanks.

Comment: It has long story so I prefer to refer you to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2142052/108128

Comment: OK. Thanks. But I think you need to mention that in your answer, because it isn't something obvious at all.

Comment: Some more explanation would work

Comment: @sadlyfe It's important that in interval $(n,n+1)$ the varieties of $[x]$ is $0$, that is $d[x]=0$. Thus the integral evaluate in jump points, they are $n$.