# Calculate a Riemann Stieltjes Integral $\int_0^3 x d([x] - x) = 3/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, change-of-variable, stieltjes-integral

I need to prove that

> $$\int_0^3 x d([x] - x)  = \dfrac32$$

However I can not think of a change of variable that can be used so I tried to approach it using Riemann Sums
 $\sum_{i=0}^3(\alpha(i)-\alpha(i-1) )i$
But I can not prove that the result is 3/2.
I took it from the Apóstol on Mathematical Analysis.

Comment: What about integrating by parts?

Comment: I can't think of how to do so.

Comment: Apostol contains such method. Refer to Section 7.5.

Comment: @xbh [Wiki: Integration by parts for R-S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties) ?

Comment: @BCLC Yes. The OP is dealing with R-S integral, so…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed this type of integrals [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141251/solve-integral-int-12x-dx2-with-floor-differential), see the details there and you find it easy
$$\int_0^3 x d([x] - x) =\int_0^3 x d[x] - \int_0^3xdx = 1+2+3-\dfrac92 = \dfrac32$$

Comment: Why $x d[x]$ and not $[x] dx$?

Comment: oh yes. I just separate the integral and didn't write the rest @BCLC

Answer (score 3):

By [Wiki: Integration by parts for R-S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties), we have

$$\int_0^3 x d([x] - x)  = 3 ([3] - 3) - 0 ([0] - 0) - \int_0^3 [x] - x dx$$

$$= 0 + 0 - \int_0^3 [x] - x dx$$

$$= \int_0^3 x - [x] dx,$$

an ordinary Riemann integral.